# Why would GetProperty() not find the property on the most derived type but would find it one of interfaces the type implements?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have some very complex object passed into my callback and I don't control the object design and don't really know what to expect there. All I know is that it likely implements an `SpecificInterface` interface that has a public getter for `SpecificProperty` public property.

I have this code:

```
dynamic theObjectPassed = ...;
Type objectType = theObjectPassed.GetType();
var objectProperty = objectType.GetProperty("SpecificProperty");
Type interfaceType = objectType.GetInterface("SpecificInterface");
var interfaceProperty = interfaceType.GetProperty("SpecificProperty");
```

and somehow `objectProperty` becomes `null` but `interfaceProperty` becomes non-null.

Why is the property found in the interface but not in the class that derives from that interface?

Comment: [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), maybe?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Ouch... How do I unsee it?

Comment: Another possibility might be that the property is implemented on a base class, and the derived class defines a non-property of the same name (hiding the base class property). (Edit: This is wrong, testing shows that `Type.GetProperty` would still find the base class property.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes that complex object is created from  must have been extending interface `SpecificInterface` by explicit interface implementation; thus unless object of class is accessed thru explicit interface, its properties are not accessible. See  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392516/Why-I-use-explicit-interface-implementation-as-a-d)